# Json Tag returns null with gson

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I am using the Gson Library to parse my JSON request in my android programme. my Json is like this

```
{
 "max_rental_rate": "9.00",
 "average_rental_rate": "6.00",
 "electricity_rate": "0.31",
 "water_rate": "2.00",
 "direct_line_exchange": "0.04",
 "buildings": [
         {
            "value": "3",
            "revision_id": "3"
         },
         {
            "value": "4",
            "revision_id": "4"
         }
      ],

      "map-image": "<img typeof=\"foaf:Image\"src=\"http://ccims.badrulmi.com/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/3quarter_view_low.jpg?itok=Ac1mv9U5\" width=\"220\" height=\"165\" />"

}
```

everyting was parsing until I reached map-image. What could be the issue here? 
below is my java code.

my parsing code:

```
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        MainContainer mainContainer = gson.fromJson(result, MainContainer.class);
```

and my maincontainer class

{

```
    private String max_rental_rate;
    private String average_rental_rate;
    private String electricity_rate;
    private String water_rate;
    private String direct_line_exchange;
    private String direct_line_remarks;
    private String internet;
    private String internet_remarks;
    private ArrayList<Buildings> buildings;
    private String mapimage;
```

}

appreciate any help.

Thank You,

Comment: Hope u added the getters and setter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Annonations:

```
 @SerializedName("map-image")
 private String mapimage;
```

Use annonations, it will tell the gson parser about the change in namespace